# % Increase value in number record

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, compare

my dataset

```
name date        record   
A    2018-09-18      95       
A    2018-10-11     104      
A    2018-10-30     230       
A    2018-11-23     124       
B    2020-01-24      95       
B    2020-02-11     167       
B    2020-03-07      78
```

As you can see, there are several records by name and date.

Compared to the previous record, I would like to see the record that rose the most.

**output what I want**

```
name record_before_date record_before record_increase_date record_increase increase_rate
A            2018-10-11           104           2018-10-30             230        121.25
B            2020-01-24            95           2020-02-11             167         75.79
```

I`m not comparing the lowest to the highest, but I want to check the record with the highest ascent rate when the next record comes, and the rate of ascent.

**increase rate formula = (record_increase - record_before) / record_before * 100**

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#get percento change per groups
s = df.groupby("name")["record"].pct_change()
#get row with maximal percent change
df1 = df.loc[s.groupby(df['name']).idxmax()].add_suffix('_increase')
#get row with previous maximal percent change
df2 = (df.loc[s.groupby(df['name'])
         .apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1).idxmax())].add_suffix('_before'))
#join together
df = pd.concat([df2.set_index('name_before'), 
                df1.set_index('name_increase')], axis=1).rename_axis('name').reset_index()
#apply formula
df['increase_rate'] = (df['record_increase'].sub(df['record_before'])
                                            .div(df['record_before'])
                                            .mul(100))
print (df)
  name date_before  record_before date_increase  record_increase  \
0    A  2018-10-11            104    2018-10-30              230   
1    B  2020-01-24             95    2020-02-11              167   

   increase_rate  
0     121.153846  
1      75.789474
```

Comment: hello @jezrael, I got an error, line 2, `'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'`

Comment: @ybin - Is possible use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before this solution?

Comment: @ybin - If there is some group with only 1 or 2 rows whats happend?

Comment: @ybin - tested and error means there is some group with only one row.

Comment: Oh I understand I'll check

Comment: @ybin - You can test them `print (df[df['name'].map(df['name'].value_counts()).eq(1)])`

Comment: @ybin - Also remove them before my solution `df= df[df['name'].map(df['name'].value_counts()).gt(1)].copy()`